# Running Ghost on port 80 through NGINX (localhost)

Tags: node.js, windows, nginx, ghost

I'm working on localhost and Windows OS. NGINX run on port 80 and Node.js app(Ghost) run on port 2368.

I want to use NGINX as front web server for Ghost app. So in `nginx.conf` file I wrote:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localghost;
    # change above to example.com in production mode
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    }
}
```

NGINX directory is `C:\nginx`, Ghost directory is `C:\nginx\www\ghost`.

`http://localghost` address is not opening Ghost app. How can i do that?

Comment: You should define where exactly "localghost" goes. You will need to edit your Windows hosts file so it goes to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Does localghost resolve to anything?

If you are testing on your development machine, then I would suggest to just use localhost and be done with it.